# How to make URL point to next successive element in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, url

I am developing a polling application using Django , it has bunch of questions with multiple options below it ..

[polling Question and its choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaLfq.png)

When i click the next button , the question has to change

I have question id and i wanted to increment the question id so that when i click the button it points to the next question.

I tried doing this

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id+1%}">
<input type="submit" value="Next"
     name="Next" class="button button5" /></form>
```

But the question.id+1 isn't working ! 
Can someone please tell me the approach to solve this!

```
urlpatterns = [
path('Home/',views.Home,name='Home'),
# ex: /polls/
path('', views.index, name='index'),
# ex: /polls/5/
path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
# ex: /polls/5/results/
path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
# ex: /polls/5/vote/
path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),]
```

How should i write the view for this?

Comment: post your views and url pattern also.

Comment: You can pass the `next_question_id` variable in the view's context.

Comment: Should i write a view for that?

Comment: @AmireddyTharunreddy Please see my answer if that works let me knw

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django template tag add to increase the number.

i.e)

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id|add:1 %}">
```

But that's not the best method. please change your method to pass the next context variable in the request and use that in form tag. Also how do you know about last question ?

Comment: Thanks it worked ! I will write conditions statements to avoid error for last question

Comment: If that works can you make this question as accepted question. ?

Comment: I tried upvoting but i don't have enough reputation .. is there any way to make it accepted !?